# Post Google plus reviews

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-one

I have a form in my site about writing a review. after form submission i need to share the review in my google plus reviews section. Is there any way to do this? While researching i found this: https://plus.google.com/account_id/about?review=1
But this did nothing.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to programmatically post to Google+ the Google+ api only allows for read operations not write.